# AWS Athena- reduce scan size

Tags: amazon-athena

How to reduce to data scanned size for 'select' query in AWS athena. By scanning only one of the column.

Example:
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUS='Fail';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to reduce the scan size would be to partition based on the data by the STATUS value.

See the [user guide for information about partitioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html).  However, you may want to consider a columnar format such as [Apache Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) as well, which is a columnar data storage and interchange format which is [supported by Athena](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/parquet.html).

Using a columnar format is helpful because Athena will only read the columns it must to satisfy the query. For a `SELECT *` query it usually won't make much of a difference, but the I/O savings can be substantial if you're only interested in a few columns out of dozens or hundreds. In addition, Parquet (and ORC, a competing columnar format also supported by Athena) support compression, so even when all columns are accessed it's still quite a savings over uncompressed CSV or JSON.

Answer (score 3):

See [Athena performance tuning tips](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/). This AWS blog has multiple tips on reducing data scanned as well as improving performance. Major ones that I see are:

- Compression (differs with file format). See [Compression formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/compression-formats.html) and [SerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/supported-format.html).
- [Partitioning the data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html).

Comment: Great response, I would add that for very wide tables (many columns) going to a columnar format can reduce scan size and cost (though it might not do much for performance as compared to partitioning and compression).